# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib

Tags: python, installation, urllib

when I try to install urllib in Python 2.715 version , its remind me that

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement urllib (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for urllib
```

who can help me to figure this out ? thanks a lot

Comment: how were you trying to install it? It is not at all clear from your question

Comment: it has been solved, urllib is default package , i dont need to install .

Answer (score 11):

This module is packaged with Python by default (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html))  So you just need to import it:

```
import urllib.request
```